# I am getting an error during JasperReport Server Installation

Tags: azure, jasperserver

I am trying to install JasperReport Server Community v8.0.0 on a vm windows server 2019 in Azure.

The installation process fails with the following error message:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly Error running C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-8.0.0/buildomatic/js-ant.bat import-minimal-ce: [create-ks] Failed to create the keystore

[View installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHZX5.png)

I searched for information about this error and found the following article:

[How to fix the installation error (buildomatic)](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-fix-installation-error-buildomatic-keystore-may-have-been-tempered)

I tried following the instructions and deleted .jrsks and .jrsksp files and these get re-created upon installation but the files are created empty 0KB.

I chose to install the bundled tomcat and postgres server during installation FYI. I am trying to set this up for a testing environment but I can't seem to get this working.

I have to mention I used the exact same installer on my development machine and it's working perfectly.

JDK 18.0.1.1 is running on the server.

UPDATE:

I also tried installing all of the services separately. I've installed tomcat standalone server as well as postgres database.

And according to the installation documentation I am using the .war installer of JasperReport Server that uses the buildomatic scripts. I have configured the default_master.properties file accordingly to my tomcat and postgres services. And when running the js-install-ce.bat I am receiving the following error message.

> [create-ks] WARNING: A new encryption key and a new keystore are about to be created.
> [create-ks] 2022-05-09T02:21:07,667 ERROR KeystoreManager:517 - Failed to create the keystore. Error: Failed to save configuration changes
> [create-ks] Failed to create the keystore
> BUILD FAILED
> C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-8.0.0\buildomatic\build.xml:58: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-8.0.0\buildomatic\bin\setup.xml:377: Keystore may have been tampered with.

For some unknown reason it is not able to create the keystore .jrsks and .jrsksp files correctly. The files are created on the expected user folder but these are created empty 0KB. These files are used by the JasperReports Server application to encrypt passwords in configuration files.

I've been fighting with this error for a few days now, any help or anything else to try would be really appreciated.

FYI. The server is running:
JDK 18.0.1.1
java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)

JAVA_HOME AND JRE_HOME env variables are set accordingly.
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1
JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333

Comment: Just in case somebody else is facing the same issue. When there is the existence of the same Windows user, either as a local account or the same user in a different domain, and the installation is done with this user, then the script creates keystore files with 0 bytes...with the error Failed to create the keystore. In my case changing the computer name to other than the user solved the issue.

Comment: Could you please answer your own question and accept it? This may help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is the existence of the same windows user, either as a local account or the same user in a different domain, and the installation is done with this user, the installation script creates keystore files with 0 bytes.

In this case the solution was to change the computer's name to a different one since when the vm was created it had the same name as the user account which was being used for the installation.